# Good books on Advanced Probability Theory with exercises to work with

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, conditional-expectation, martingales

I am interested in advanced Probability Theory books which also do have lots of **exercises** to work with, in the topics of convergence of random variables, conditional expectation (martingales in particular).

Does anybody have any good suggestions?

Comment: Schilling's "Measures , integrals and martingales"

Comment: K L Chung's A Course in ProbabilityTheory.

Comment: also you can take a look at the book of François Le Gall of Brownian motion

Comment: Mathematical statistics (Shao) is the one I used. It has a lot of exercises and there is also a book with solutions for many of them.

Answer (score 2):

My go-to probability book is Rick Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, which is available [online for free](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) from his website.